# How to republish SharePoint 2013 workflows via Powershell farm-wide

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-on-prem, workflow-manager-farm

I have a SharePoint farm with Dedicated WFM farm which is working fine, Now i am splitting SharePoint farm in to two farms (Farm A and Farm B) but workflow manager farm will be remain same. Everything is working fine after the split expect SharePoint 2013 workflows. I am getting the Scope not found error when i try to run the workflows in farm B (it is expected that scope of the WFM change in farm B).

> getInstances threw exception:
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ScopeNotFoundException: Scope
>   '/SharePoint/default/ad2f730d-7d0c-417d-972f-df9a2d992506/c352cde2-28b2-4b54-a7ee-3ad215a6b726'
>   was not found.  HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
>   dsdd9142-62af-4df0-ad2b-297f6713e70. NodeId: KFWFM. Scope:
>   /SharePoint/default/0d-7d0c-417d-972f-df9a2d992506/cde2-28b2-4b54-a7ee-3ad215a6b726.
>   Client ActivityId : aebf9e-b173-a0e9-9225-ccda760a9ba5. --->
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult
>   result)     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult
>   result)     at
>   Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest
>   r...  64aebf9e-b173-a0e9-9225-ccda760a9ba5

Now question, is their a way to identify and re published the Sharepoint 2013 Only workflows in farm b using powershell.

or what is way to migrate the SharePoint 2013 workflows from one scope to different.